# Is it possible to create a pdf from a firebase collection in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have a collection 'orders' in my database and I would like to create a report of it in PDF so I can print it. Is it possible to have it with flutter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by using the following package:

https://pub.dev/packages/pdf

After you retrieve your data you can use this package to create a pdf file. Also it would be easy to design a pdf page as this package use a widget system similar to Flutter widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, through a combination of the [`printing`](https://pub.dev/packages/printing) and [`pdf`](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) packages.